# Hijack output from aspx

Tags: asp.net, pdf-generation

I want to convert an aspx page to PDF using a component that can convert Html to PDF. Is it possible to, during post back, redirect the output from the aspx-page and send it as a stream or string to a HtmlToPdf method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    // setup a TextWriter to capture the page markup
    TextWriter tw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);

    // render the page into our surrogate TextWriter
    base.Render(htw);

    // convert the TextWriter markup to a string
    string pageSource = tw.ToString();

    if (convertToPDF)
    {
        // convert the page markup to a pdf
        // eg, byte[] pdfBytes = HtmlToPdf(pageSource);
    }

    // write the page markup into the output stream
    writer.Write(pageSource);
}
```

Comment: Tanks Luke. This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to send the value returned from "HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream;" in the postback ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think that the way to do this would be to use the Reponse.Filter property to intercept and alter the HTML being sent to a page.

There's a tutorial video and sample code in both VB.net and C# on this page on the ASP.net website:

http://www.asp.net/learn/videos/video-450.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You would write an HttpFilter that is attached to the request. This is code that can change the output after it has been written by the ASP.NET Page's Render step.

[This article](http://aspnetresources.com/articles/HttpFilters.aspx) shows how to do this (they change the output from HTML to valid XHTML, but the idea is the same).